# Highlight cell if month matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight the Month cell if month matches in the first 4 cells.

[image]

For example, in first row I need to highlight E2 rather than E4. If there is no value in the first 4 cells, then i dont need to highlight any of the month cells.

I am trying with conditional formatting, but not able to nail it.

**What I want**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
=OR((NOT(ISBLANK($A2:$D2))*(MONTH($A2:$D2)=E$1))>0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. It also works if there are >1 date in a row. Exactly what i needed. Cheers